# C++ Vectors and struct pointers

Tags: c++, vector, struct, malloc

My struct has a vector of integers. However, when dynamically creating an instance of the struct, I can't seem to access the vector.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    vector<int> intList;
} astruct;

int main()
{
    astruct* myStruct = (astruct*) malloc(sizeof(astruct));
    myStruct->intList.push_back(100);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    free(myStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to add 100 to the struct's vector crashes the program. Hello world! is never shown. What's going on?

Comment: wow malloc...  might just want to use `new` there.  malloc won't probably construct the vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector is never initialized as you simply cast an allocated memory region to a `astruct*`, therefor the constructor of your struct and as consequence the constructor of `std::vecotr` is never called. Use the **new operator** instead.

```
astruct* myStruct = new astruct();
myStruct->intList.push_back(100);
delete myStruct;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `malloc()`/`free()` in C++ program, especially for creating C++ object, unless you know what you are doing. So use `new`/`delete` instead:

```
int main()
{
    astruct* myStruct = new astruct;
    myStruct->intList.push_back(100);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    delete(myStruct);
    return 0;
}
```